# EditorSceneManager using SceneManager in Play mode test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, editor, scene

I would need to use EditorSceneManager to load the scene for play mode unit test.
I need to use this one and not SceneManager.Load since I cannot have the scene in Build settings. The documentation about EditorSceneManager is clear that it is supposed to do what I need.

```
    protected void LoadScene(string sceneName, Action onComplete)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sceneName)) { Debug.LogError("Missing scene name"); return;}
        UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
        //...
    }
```

I get error that the scene is not in the build settings as if SceneManager.LoadScene was called instead of the editor version.

Compiler also suggests to simplify to the following that I do not want to use:

```
 UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
```

though I have no directives that could confuse the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
```

I was using a side solution with IPrebuildSetup, IPostBuildCleanup to add/remove the scene via the AssetDatabase and EditorBuildSettingsScene and it works. But it also runs the scene loading/unloading process in Jenkins while building the prod app. I need to avoid that since it could lead to shipping assets that are only used in test scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `EditorSceneManager` inherits from `SceneManager` that's why it provides the same method `LoadScene` which afaik does the same thing, meaning there is no override or something like this for the `EditorSceneManager`.

However it provides additional methods you can and should use for editor specific stuff.

You can use [`LoadSceneInPlayMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.LoadSceneInPlayMode.html)

> This method allows you to load a Scene during playmode in the editor, **without requiring the Scene to be included in the Build Settings Scene list.**

```
UnityEditor.SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.LoadSceneInPlayMode(sceneName);
```

**Note**: The parameter is called `path`, not `sceneName`, for a reason ;)

You have to provide the path as it is stored in [`Scene.path`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-path.html)

> Returns the relative path of the Scene. Like: **"Assets/MyScenes/MyScene.unity"**

Comment: Ok, that actually was it. I have used that one and its async version to no avail, I would just get an empty scene with the right naming. The problem is in the scene path, it needs to be as "Assets/<full_path>/sceneName.unity" and not just scene name as I did. Maybe you want to add that to the answer since I can see the problem to be a bit all over Google and most of the time it ends with "Ok I fixed it" and no actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should just write a

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
```

And then you can load the scene with

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);
```

Should be ok like this

Comment: I cannot use that one since it requires the scene to be added to Build settings.

Comment: maybe this is useful : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.EditorSceneManager.LoadSceneInPlayMode.html